# Find Duplicate Records with Special & Other Characters

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance

We are into a situation where we are importing customer records from 3rd party application,
and 
while interacting with another interface we are receiving customer request if customer match not found we are inserting new customer.

If exact customer match not found then the Customer get duplicated.

Now there is no way to hand shake between above two interface and get the correct customer

So now we need to develop tool to remove duplicate customer

Can some one please suggest what will be the best way to achieve this.

Levenshtein distance could be one option? other?

In terms of performance as well because we have more than 5000 customers

Example that we need to handle is

```
Customer 1 - abcsÿdesλ

Customer 2 - abcsfdesd

Customer 3 - úbcsfdμsd
```

All the above customer are same and need to merge to one.

We need to compare the customer on basics of at least 5 fields like first name, last name etc.

Please advise, Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how those errors happened, [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) may be possible alternatives. Soundex compares possible pronounciations, while Levenshtein compares just characters.

If the errors happened because the names were written down while on the phone, where the pronounciation was clear but the spelling was not, then Soundex might be an option. If the names were misspelled because of typos, unreadable mail or bad OCR, then Soundex is basically worthless and Levenshtein is a very good fit.

All comparison routines will return a value of how similar the inputs were. You will need two thresholds, one for the whole record and one for each field. You want the record as a whole (the sum of all fields) to be below a certain value *and* you want each field on it's own below a certain value.

Sometimes you may want to introduce special meanings to those numbers or have field-dependencies. For example: if you have sex or salutation, if those matches, the match on first name can be less strict. If sex/salutation does not match, you better be strict on the first name, because even a single letter can seperate two obviously different persons. Think of Mario and Maria or Angelo and Angela. You don't want to put Mr. Angelo and Mrs. Angela as the same person. That would be hard to explain.

Last but not least, 5000 records is nothing. If you put that in a database, you can just have a loop comparing all 5000 to your input record.

Should you have many more records in the future, you need a field that you are very sure of being correct to pick only a few records to compare with. The zipcode for example is often spelled out on the phone and well structured, so it will seldom be wrong. Pick all records with the same zipcode or similar likely correct field from the database to reduce the number of records you have to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback
But with around 5000 records to compare 1 field with 4999 times taking around 3 mins that means with 5 fields it would take 15 mins.

Any option to improve the performance.

Comment: @KeshavdasM 15 mins does not really sound like a long time, if this is a one-time operation. You should definitely _not_ create a solution where you need to do this again and again on regular basis. Get it done once, place the results in a new DB, and use only that going forward. Also, one more thing: If you can group your records by some other piece of information than name, perhaps you can rely only on comparisons within groups? That might reduce the number of comparisons significantly...

Comment: Thank you, was exactly doing the same, applying the filter on other parameters and at end using Levenshtein algorithm to exactly find the match